# Why does the cmake build not set the path in quotes?

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I have Visual Studio Pro 2019 (VS) and I switched NDK versions, from 16 to 18.

The thing is, my ndk 16 was an old one, from Android Studio, and the new one, I installed directly from VS (Tools/Android/Android SDK Manager)

My project uses cmake files among other things to build, and I have to include the new path for the ndk into them.

The new path to the ndk contains more SPACE characters, and that's what's troubleing me.

I build my project, and the following error occurs:

```
The C compiler
3>  
3>      "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"
3>  
3>    is not able to compile a simple test program.
3>  
3>    It fails with the following output:
3>  
3>      Change Dir: D:/Repos/Client_main/client/BuildResults/CustomDebug_AndroidArm_MRClient/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
3>      
3>      Run Build Command(s):ninja.exe cmTC_633e0 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_633e0.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
3>      FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_633e0.dir/testCCompiler.c.o 
3>      C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\NDK-BU~1\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi27 --gcc-toolchain="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64" --sysroot="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot"   -isystem C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -fPIE -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_633e0.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c testCCompiler.c
3>D:\Repos\Client_main\client\MediaroomAndroidApp\clang.exe : error : no such file or directory: 'Files'
3>D:\Repos\Client_main\client\MediaroomAndroidApp\clang.exe : error : no such file or directory: '(x86)/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'
3>      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

After my research, I found out, that the following parameter is the cause of the problem:

```
-isystem C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
```

It should be with quotes (-isystem "C:...").
I have no idea how to do that, it is not my code, it seems that the cmake is building the command for clang.exe to run, but I have no idea how to correct it.

Any ideas?

Edit 1: CMAKE command:

```
  <CmakeCommand><![CDATA[
call "$(VsToolsDir)VsDevCmd.bat" -no_logo
cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="$(MstvBuildTypeDir)" -DBUILD_PLATFORM:STRING="Android" -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN:STRING="clang" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:STRING="Android" -DANDROID_API_LEVEL:STRING="27" -DANDROID_PLATFORM:STRING="android-27" -DANDROID_ABI:STRING="armeabi-v7a" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="C:/PROGRA~2/Android/ANDROI~1/NDK-BU~1/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION:STRING="27" -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI:STRING="armeabi-v7a" -DANDROID_STL:STRING="c++_shared" -DBUILD_TYPE:STRING="$(NativeLowercaseConfig)" -DBUILD_VARIANT:STRING="$(NativeLowercaseVariant)" -DBUILD_TARGET:STRING="Arm" -DCMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED:STRING="TRUE" -DTOOLCHAIN_ROOT:STRING="C:/PROGRA~2/Android/ANDROI~1/NDK-BU~1/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="$(Configuration)" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="ninja.exe" "$(MstvClientDir)"
]]></CmakeCommand>
```

Edit 2:
I read all over that the LLVM directory (in there is clang.exe) MUST NOT be on a path containing SPACEs, is this still the case with version 7.0.2?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Move the project to a path without spaces?

Comment: That would work (already done that, but had to revert the change) but I need it to be there (the default path for ndk) because a lot other scripts are using it from there.

Comment: @squareskittles I have added the cmake command to the post mby you can see something usefull :)

Comment: Try to configure with that toolchain "empty" CMake project, which `CMakeLists.txt` consists only from two lines: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)` and `project(foo)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev forgive me, I dont understand, by "empty" the toolchain, you mean to remove the following line from the cmake command? (-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING="C:/PROGRA~2/Android/ANDROI~1/NDK-BU~1/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake"), and for the second part, you want my main CMakeLists.txt file to consist of those 2 lines you mentiond? Also, is it maybe better to remove that -isystem flag, and if yes, how? I tried with -DCMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED:STRING="YES"  but it didn't work

Comment: No, I mean using the same toolchain with the same parameters, but not for your project which we don't see, but for the 2-lines project which only "activates" the toolchain but otherwise does nothing. I know, that projects rarely put something before a `project()` call, which triggers a compiler detection and checking. But your problem implies going deeper in the toolchain aspects, which are quite non-trivial and are poor documented. Before doing that, I want to be sure that the project itself is not responsible for the problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, my problem goes deeper, and yes, it is very poor documented. As for the project, it is legit, there were no problems before my NDK change. And now I came across the solution that uses a symbolic link to bypass the program files x86 problem. I made the link, without spaces ofc, and it worked...Not ideal, but for now it'll work. Thank you for your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I could not solve the problem as I wanted to, but found a diferent solution that keeps the NDK in its original position.

I made a symbolic link like this:

```
mklink /J C:\ProFiles86 "C:\Program Files (x86)"
```

Afterwards, I changed my path in order to use the link (C:\ProFiles86...) and it worked.

Again, this is not ideal for me, because it requires an aditional script to be included in my project, but for now it'll do.